# Kubernetes Docker version upgrade | Fix error “unexpected EOF”

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gcloud, docker-machine

I have seen that gcloud kubernetes is using Docker version 17.03.2-ce, build f5ec1e2.
Where as the I want to have docker version Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4

The error “* Fix error “unexpected EOF” when adding an 8GB file moby/moby#37771” has been resolved in the latter version of docker.

Is there any way i can manually upgrade the version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Google Kubernetes engine you should have Node OS as Ubuntu. Then you should use a DeamonSet as start-up script with the following yaml file below:

```
kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ssd-startup-script
  labels:
    app: ssd-startup-script
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ssd-startup-script
    spec:
      hostPID: true
      containers:
      - name: ssd-startup-script
        image: gcr.io/google-containers/startup-script:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        env:
        - name: STARTUP_SCRIPT
          value: |
            #!/bin/bash
            sudo curl -s https://get.docker.com/ | sh
            echo Done
```

Then you have the Docker version should be like below:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.0
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        4d60db4
 Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:49:01 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```